# JMeter - state, nonce, code Parameters in GET request

Tags: performance, jmeter, get, state, nonce

I am trying to variablize the state, nonce, and code for GET requests for my JMeter script.  I am able to successfully generate a random string of 50 characters (for state and nonce) and can generate a random string in the format of [8 characters]-[4 characters]-[4 characters]-[4 characters]-[12 characters] :where 'characters' lowercase alphabet and digits.

However, when I pass these variables thru as parameters, the GET request will fail.

It does however succeed when I hard code the original value of each variable from the HTTPS Script Recorder into the GET request,  and change the last character to an 'x', for example.

I will need to variablize these parameters as I cannot hard code for each and every GET request when testing for hundreds of users.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

variablizing the following in the User Defined Variables, and passing them thru to the GET requests:

varState = ${__RandomString(50,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}
varNonce = ${__RandomString(50,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}
varCode = ${__RandomString(8,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}-${__RandomString(4,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}-${__RandomString(4,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}-${__RandomString(4,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}-${__RandomString(12,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}

I am, of course, expecting this this to work.  But sadly it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You sadly don't understand how do [OAuth flows](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use) work.

1. `state`. As per [Prevent Attacks and Redirect Users with OAuth 2.0 State Parameters](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/attack-protection/state-parameters) `state` parameter is being used for [CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) attacks prevention so it needs to be extracted from the previous response. See [What is CSRF & How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-csrf-load-testing) for more details
2. `code`. It's unclear what exactly "code" you have in mind, most probably it needs to be extracted from the previous response as well, see [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/server-side-apps/authorization-code/) article for example explanation
3. `nonce` is indeed random, but make sure that it's the same across the flow. See [Nonce Implementation Notes](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#NonceNotes)